# Sending Fault Messages to Topic Subscription Dead Letter Queue with Masstransit and Azure Service Bus

Tags: masstransit

When a subscriber of a topic throws an exception non-handled message lands in `{subscribername}_error` queue.

Given the example:

```
const string subsriberName = "AnotherSubscriber";
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<AnotherThingHappened>(host, subsriberName, configurator =>
{
    configurator.Handler<AnotherThingHappened>(context =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(context.Message.AnotherThingType);
        if (Random.NextDouble() < 0.1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Oups, I failed :(");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

It created "AnotherSubscriber" subscription on topic ObjectCreatedA. But when it fails the message goes to the queue `anothersubscriber_error`. It makes it harder to diagnose, monitor and replay messages. Because from ASB perspective this is just an ordinary queue.

[image]

How do I route failures to the DLQ of topic ObjectCratedA/AnotherSubscriber instead of `**_error` one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, MassTransit doesn't work that way.

Comment: May I ask, why it was designed this way? E.g. if I have a WebJob that listens for 5 types of events, then I need to create 5 Subscription Endpoints with unique names like WebJobType, then errors from those handlers will end up in one queue which is quite messy. I cannot replay them easily.

Comment: So create a unique subscription name for each type? I dunno, that's just the way it works. If you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears, but I don't believe you can write messages to a subscription DLQ.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible as of MassTransit 6.2, see the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1252).

Your configuration will now need to look something like:

```
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint(
    "my-subscription",
    "my-topic",
    e =>
    {
        e.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(provider);
        // Send failures to built-in Azure Service Bus Dead Letter queue
        e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
        e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();
    });
```

Comment: but how do you do this with a ReceiveEndpoint that has a topic subscription. BECAUSE if i try to go into the DLQ of the queue and 'resend' from the DLQ it gives an error because the queue is populated by an auto send subscriber. Probably we need a way to redirect to the TOPIC's DLQ from the ReceiveEndpoitn Queue?