# MassTransit UseMessageRetry in ConsumerDefinition for BatchConsumer throws error on startup

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm trying to set up a batch consumer for a subscription on an Azure Service Bus topic. Not really getting it to work. With the setup below, there will be an exception on startup because of the message retry configuration in `BatchConsumerDefinition`.

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. If I disable the retries, it starts. But failed messages do not end up on the DLQ of the subscription. Why is that?

Thanks!

```
services.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddConsumer<BatchMessageEventConsumer, BatchConsumerDefinition>();

    configurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, factoryConfigurator) =>
    {
        factoryConfigurator.Host(asbConnectionString);

        factoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint<IMessageEvent>("my-subscription", endpointConfigurator =>
        {
            endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumer<BatchMessageEventConsumer>(context);
            endpointConfigurator.Batch<IMessageEvent>(x =>
            {
                x.Consumer<BatchMessageEventConsumer, IMessageEvent>(context); // provider, context, etc.
            });
        });
    });
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
```

```
public class BatchConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<BatchMessageEventConsumer>
{
    public BatchConsumerDefinition()
    {
        Endpoint(x => x.PrefetchCount = 1000);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<BatchMessageEventConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        // This will cause startup to throw: "System.ArgumentException: 'The type or method has 1 generic parameter(s), but 2 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter.'"
        consumerConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

        consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(options => options
            .SetMessageLimit(100)
            .SetTimeLimit(1000)
            .SetConcurrencyLimit(10));
    }
}
```

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The type or method has 1 generic parameter(s), but 2 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter.'

   at System.RuntimeType.SanityCheckGenericArguments(RuntimeType[] genericArguments, RuntimeType[] genericParamters)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   at MassTransit.PipeConfigurators.MessageRetryConsumerConfigurationObserver`1.MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators.IConsumerConfigurationObserver.ConsumerMessageConfigured[T,TMessage](IConsumerMessageConfigurator`2 configurator)
   at MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators.ConsumerConfigurationObservable.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<ConsumerMessageConfigured>b__0(IConsumerConfigurationObserver observer)
   at GreenPipes.Util.Connectable`1.All(Func`2 callback)
   at MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators.ConsumerConfigurationObservable.ConsumerMessageConfigured[TConsumer,TMessage](IConsumerMessageConfigurator`2 configurator)
   at MassTransit.ConsumerSpecifications.BatchConsumerMessageSpecification`2.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Validate>b__0(IConsumerConfigurationObserver observer)
   at GreenPipes.Util.Connectable`1.All(Func`2 callback)
   at MassTransit.ConsumerSpecifications.BatchConsumerMessageSpecification`2.Validate()
   at MassTransit.ConsumerSpecifications.ConsumerSpecification`1.<>c.<Validate>b__7_1(IConsumerMessageSpecification`1 x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at MassTransit.ConsumerSpecifications.ConsumerSpecification`1.<Validate>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at MassTransit.Configuration.ReceiveEndpointConfiguration.<Validate>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MassTransit.Configurators.BusConfigurationResult..ctor(IEnumerable`1 results)
   at MassTransit.Configurators.BusConfigurationResult.CompileResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
   at MassTransit.Registration.TransportRegistrationBusFactory`1.CreateBus[T,TConfigurator](T configurator, IBusRegistrationContext context, Action`2 configure, IEnumerable`1 specifications)
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Configuration.ServiceBusRegistrationBusFactory.CreateBus(IBusRegistrationContext context, IEnumerable`1 specifications)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.CreateBus[T](T busFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<SetBusFactory>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.Registration.ServiceCollectionBusConfigurator.<>c__7`1.<SetBusFactory>b__7_1(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at MassTransit.HostedServiceConfigurationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddMassTransitHostedService>g__HostedServiceFactory|0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: I did [find a bug](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2594) in the message retry configuration for consumer-specific retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove the duplicate consumer from your configuration.

The subscription endpoint should be configured as shown:

```cs
factoryConfigurator.SubscriptionEndpoint<IMessageEvent>("my-subscription", endpointConfigurator =>
{
    endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumer<BatchMessageEventConsumer>(context);
});
```

Also, you should change your definition to:

```cs
public class BatchConsumerDefinition : 
    ConsumerDefinition<BatchMessageEventConsumer>
{
    public BatchConsumerDefinition()
    {
        Endpoint(x => x.PrefetchCount = 1000);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<BatchMessageEventConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

        consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(options => options
            .SetMessageLimit(100)
            .SetTimeLimit(1000)
            .SetConcurrencyLimit(10));
    }
}
```

That might resolve it.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks! I got confused because of the retry configuration not working in the consumer definition and then I just tried a couple of things back and forth.

Comment: I'm browsing the MassTransit code and trying to figure out why messages aren't moved to the DLQ, unless I have retry configured. Could you point me in the right direction maybe?

Comment: You [need the two Configure methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056290/1882) (valid for regular or subscription endpoints) to specify that the dead letter queue should be used for error/skipped messages.

Comment: Huh, ok. Thanks. Yeah I feel stupid now, I've done that for the receive endpoints already. But I'm sure I've tried that before but must have had some other issue at the same time then.